# Downloadable code examples for OOP design-patterns in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Does anyone know of some good downloadable visual studio solution files that explain all the GOF design-patterns (and their variants if possible) in .NET (C# preferred)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For some good short code examples, check this [Design Patterns in C# and VB.Net](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)

Comment: +1 - not a bad site and their code samples provide both theoretical and applied examples for each pattern.